# How does Devise make current_user available to both controllers and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

By what mechanism does [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) make the `current_user` method available to both controllers and views in Rails? I've looked at the [source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) but don't see how they do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [helper_method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method) as you can see here: [helpers.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L129) and bellow:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  helper_method "current_#{mapping}", "#{mapping}_signed_in?", "#{mapping}_session"
end
```

If you search that file by `current_user` you won't find anything because devise uses `mapping` placeholder to allow you to do something like:

```
rails generate devise User # this will generate 3 helpers: current_user, user_signed_in? and user_session
```

or

```
rails generate devise Blogger # this will generate 3 helpers: current_blogger, blogge_signed_in? and blogger_session
```